# Need to use name of current button in the associated Acrobat javascript code

Tags: javascript, button, acrobat

I need to insert several (50+) buttons on an Acrobat document, each of which simply does a "Save As" on a specific non-PDF attachment.  For a single button, the following script works perfectly:

```
this.exportDataObject({cName:"Attachment01", nLaunch:0})
```

It would be much simpler if I could use the name of the current/calling button in the javascript like this:

```
var currButtonName = ???
this.exportDataObject({cName:currButtonName, nLaunch:0})
```

With this second approach, I could use the name of the button to determine which attachment is saved, so that I don't have to change the javascript code at all.

Is it possible to get the name of the current button and if so how?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Using

```
var currButtonName = event.target.name ;
```

or something based on event.target.name should do what you want to accomplish.